# How could I maintain the chainability within click plugin function?

Tags: jquery

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RwmpU/)

```
(function(){
   $.fn.myFunc = function(s){
   var t = this, s = $(s);
      s.on('click',function(){
         t.toggle('slow');
      });
   };
}(jQuery));

$(document).ready(function($){
    $('#world')
     .myFunc('#hello')
     .css('background-color','blue');
     //css method is not chained. How to chain?
});
```

What have I tried so far?

**1:**

```
(function(){
   $.fn.myFunc = function(s){
   var t = this, s = $(s);
   
      s.on('click',function(){
         t.each(function(){
          t.toggle('slow');
         });
      });
   };
}(jQuery));
```

**2:**

```
(function(){
   $.fn.myFunc = function(s){
   var t = this, s = $(s);
    t.each(function(){   
      s.on('click',function(){
          t.toggle('slow');
         });
      });
   };
}(jQuery));
```

Or, am I doing wrong? How should I do?

Comment: the demo http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SnWkL/2/ is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the element set (`this`) from the plugin to enable chaining of a plugin

```
(function () {
    $.fn.myFunc = function (s) {
        var t = this,
            s = $(s);
        s.on('click', function () {
            t.toggle('slow');
        });
        return this;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SnWkL/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the context back using `return this....`

In your case

```
(function(){
   $.fn.myFunc = function(s){
   var t = this, s = $(s);
      s.on('click',function(){
         t.toggle('slow');
      });
return t;
   };
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(){
   $.fn.myFunc = function(s){
   var t = this, s = $(s);
      s.on('click',function(){
         t.toggle('slow');
      });
       return this;
   };
}(jQuery));
```

Use **return this** at last

Answer (score 0):

here is the updated code.

```
(function(){
   $.fn.myFunc = function(s){
   var t = this, s = $(s);
      return s.on('click',function(){
         t.toggle('slow');
      });
   };
}(jQuery));

$(document).ready(function($){
    $('#world')
     .myFunc('#hello')
     .css('background-color','blue');
     //css method is not chained. How to chain?
});
```

Whenever you create any plugin you have to make it return to maintain the chainability.

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/RwmpU/1/